# DateTime insertion and then selection: sequence contains no elements

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-4

My table structure in sql server is :

```
TableId int (Pk) identity

Data string

DateNTime DateTime
```

---

My method is::

```
public int insertData(string data){

Date= DateTime.Now;

Table table= new Table();

table.Data= data;

table.DateNTime=Date;

 this.DataContext.Set<Table>().Add(table);

this.DataContext.SaveChanges();

return this.DataContext.Tables.Single(b => b.DateNTime == Date).TableId

}
```

The data insertion happens without any problems but in 9 out of 10 times while returning TableId I get the exception "sequence contains no elements"

Could it be that before the table row is saved the select command is fired and I get this error, if so what do I do?

Thanks
Arnab

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SaveChanges()` is a synchronous "blocking" operation, it doesn't return before the transaction that saves the date is committed. So, when you call the query the date is definitely saved in the database.

I think, it is a precision/rounding problem. If you look at the precision of a `DateTime` in .NET you'll see (for example in the `TimeOfDay` property):

**TimeOfDay of .NET `DateTime` type: 10:32:51.0312500**

So, the precision is 10E-7 seconds. A `datetime` in SQL Server has only 10E-3 seconds precision and the .NET `DateTime` is saved like this in the database:

**Column value of SQL Server `datetime` type: 10:32:51.030**

So, it is rounded to three digits. When you run the query the .NET `DateTime` is transmitted with high precision (as type `datetime2(7)` in SQL Server) ...

```
WHERE [Extent1].[MyDateTimeColumn] = @p__linq__0',
    N'@p__linq__0 datetime2(7)', @p__linq__0='2012-05-18 10:32:51.0312500'
```

... and the equality comparison fails because

`2012-05-18 10:32:51.0312500` != `2012-05-18 10:32:51.030`

If you want a higher precision use a `datetime2(7)` as type in SQL Server that matches the .NET `DateTime` type. Or avoid such queries for equality and instead query for an interval of +/- 1 second or something around your `DateTime` value, like so:

```
var date1 = Date.AddSeconds(-1);
var date2 = Date.AddSeconds( 1);
return this.DataContext.Tables
    .Single(b => b.DateNTime >= date1 && b.DateNTime <= date2)
    .TableId;
```

(Not a good solution of course if you save faster than every 2nd second, `Single` might fail with "Sequence contains more than one element" exception.)