# Compare Date values in Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net, linq, entity-framework, date, comparison

I'm trying to compare date values in entity framework.

```
DateTime selectedDate = Calendar1.SelectedDate;      
var result = context.EventsTable.Where(ev =>ev.EventDate.Equals(selectedDate));
```

ev.EventDate is coming from SQL Server 2008 and selectedDate is ASP:Calendar's Selected date.
In SQL Server 2008 date is stored as: 2012-09-03 00:00:00 
whereas date value from Calendar's SelectedDate is in 2012-09-03 12:00:00AM format.

Comment: Dates are dates.  The display format has nothing to do with storage or computation.  Is your code working?

Comment: My code is working but comparison fails, although dates are same.

Comment: That probably means that they're different by a couple of milliseconds, or that there is a hidden time zone issue.

Comment: Could be a rounding/precision problem if you use `datetime` as type in SQL Server: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11620980/270591 Note that `datetime` in SQL Server is less precise than `DateTime` in .NET. `datetime2` in SQL Server is better suited to be mapped from `DateTime` in .NET.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably truncate `EventDate`:

```
context.EventsTable
    .Where(ev => EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(ev.EventDate) == selectedDate)
```

provided that `selectedDate` is truncated as well (by `DateTime.Date`).